# Do we know exactly where Kirk will be born?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-2009, captain-kirk

I'm an amateur Star Trek fan--I've watched some of TOS and a few movies, but I know enough to remember that Captain Kirk is from Iowa.  I don't know where in Iowa, just Iowa.

Recently I came across a town (Riverside, Iowa) that claims to be the future birthplace of James T. Kirk.  According to [this article](http://www.roadsideamerica.com/story/2081), someone just chose Riverside out of the blue, without evidence from canon.

My question is, does it say anywhere in Star Trek canon where exactly Kirk <strike>was</strike> will be born?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Real World

According to the Humboldt Travel Journal, the decision to commemorate [Riverside, Iowa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverside,_Iowa#Star_Trek) as the birthplace of James Kirk was originally intended to act as a tourist attractor. After the success of the first Trek-con, the Council then decided to build a dedicated Star Trek museum.

> This phenomenon is the brainchild of Riverside City Council Member
> Steve Miller. In March of 1985, Miller suggested to the City Council,
> which was looking for a theme for the annual town festival, to
> celebrate Riverside as the future birthplace of James Tiberius Kirk,
> the infamous captain of the U.S.S. Enterprise on NBC's late 1960s
> sci-fi series "Star Trek." The future historical birth, which is set
> to take place on March 22, 2228, is also celebrated annually by the
> people of Riverside.
>
> **"I had read in Stephen Whitefield and Gene Roddenberry's 'Making of
> Star Trek' that Kirk was born in a small town in Iowa," said Miller.
> "So out of the clear blue sky, I made a motion at the City Council
> meeting that we designate Riverside as Kirk's future birthplace."**
>
> <sub><sup>[Deep Space Iowa: The Captain Kirk Museum - Humbold Journal](https://web.archive.org/web/20040220140812/http://www.humboldt.edu/%7Etravel/2003/ratner.html)</sup></sub>

### Prime Timeline (Main canon)

All we know is that Kirk's (original) birthplace was in Iowa. No specific town is mentioned.

### Alternate timeline (Abramverse Canon)

Kirk was *born* on a [shuttle in deep space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxbJJ995Vjo), then *raised* in Riverside, Iowa next to the [Riverside Shipyards](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Riverside_Shipyard) where the Enterprise was under construction.

> “We’re at the Riverside shipyard inspecting construction of a new
> vessel. Shuttle for new recruits leaves tomorrow oh-six hundred.” He
> hesitated, then locked eyes one last time with the younger man
> standing across from him. “Your father was the captain of a starship
> for twelve minutes. He saved eight hundred lives, including your
> mother’s and yours. I dare you to do better.” Pivoting sharply, he
> headed for the door.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek (2009): Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_(novel))</sup></sub>

### EU Canon

Many authors, including William Shatner (the actor who protrayed Kirk in the main canon shows and films) have made mention that Kirk was born in Riverside, Iowa.

> “Okay. That’s you, I guess,” she said. “Where are you from?”
>
> “Riverside.”
>
> “Sounds pretty. Is it a Federation colony?”
>
> Abruptly self-conscious, Jimmy realized he hadn’t added the main part
> of his address. He was used to being with people who already knew.
> “No… it’s in Iowa.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek TOS: Best Destiny](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Best_Destiny)</sup></sub>

and

> Joseph brightened. “I remember the horses.” They’d gone to a ranch
> resort in Iowa near the site of the Kirk family farm, on the outskirts
> of Riverside. But the land was now a world heritage park, and not even
> the foundations of the house or the barn had remained. Kirk recalled
> that, in an earlier time, there’d even been a statue of himself
> nearby. But that was gone, too. The old saying was true: Fame was
> fleeting. Nor could it compare with the simple joy of riding with his
> child.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek TOS: Captain's Glory by William Shatner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain%27s_Glory)</sup></sub>

Comment: Great answer.  I doubt I'll get anything better than this.

Comment: And of course, one might assume that since the Abramverse continuity was changed by time travel, had there not been a mission to investigate the 'lightning storm' and the stress of the following events triggered a premature birth, they might well have been back at Earth and at Riverside in the original timeline in time for his birth.

Comment: @starpilotsix: Wait, this would mean that for Riverside's  claim to be correct, we have to degenerate from the first Enterprise starship (NX-01) to creepy beeps, awfully small monitors, mechanical switches, really bad taste in ship design, clothing, and haircut, and so on before building THE Enterprise (NCC-1701)? Holy crap!

Comment: And note that all of the **canon** references to Riverside _post_-date the adoption by the Riverside Council of the designation.

Comment: And the shady marketing guy wins again...